# How to repair a table surface?

Tags: repair, furniture

The table is a bean shaped hollow structure made of two 4mm hardboard panels and has a convex siding. The top surface and the sidings are coated seamlessly.

It's 40mm thick and about 1.5 square meters in area, and I don't need to process the bottom side, just the upper surface and the sidings.

The table has few holes (up to 7mm in diameter) and many scratches all over the surface and sidings (up to 2mm deep).

I need to repair it and hopefully make it better then buying a new one.

1. I want it to be opaque non-glossy dark blue color.
2. Also I want it inflammable, safe for food, washable and kind of resistant to kid's technical experiments.

What kind and amount of coating, dye or other materials to use, what tools do I need, and what is the process?

Comment: Some kind of food grade epoxy is coming to mind. That's a pretty tall order of specifications. Sounds like you might be better off topping with something like Plexiglas after painting it the color you want. Then the top is semi-disposable.

Comment: I want the surface to be matte and seamless with sidings, also Plexiglas would need to be cut to the bean shape, so i'd better stick to some coating and painting. When it comes to just using epoxy coating and a painting, can you suggest the exact specs?

Comment: Unfortunately not, these are just things that come to mind generally. Also, this Stack Exchange is more meant to be a "how to", rather than a product recommendation and/or shopping help. I would simply search for "Epoxy worktop coating" and start there. Good luck on your project!